# Barcode decoding with pyzbar on raspberry pi

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, zbar

I am using pyzbar to decode barcodes on Raspberry Pi 3 using Pi Camera v1 (resolution 1296x972). Qr codes are decoded very well. When decoding two dimensional barcodes (CODABAR), the success rate is very low.

I have tried saving one frame from the video stream and decode it with pyzbar on the Raspberry and it fails. When i try to decode the same image on Ubuntu, and decodes it successfully.

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('sampleImage.png')
d = pyzbar.decode(img)

print (d)
```

Any thoughts what may be the problem?

**UPDATE:**

The following image is my specific use case. 
[image: eBarcode image]
Because I am using Pi Camera v1 to take images, I tried to do adjustment to image sharpness:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
self.camera = PiCamera()
self.camera.sharpness = 100
```

The following image is with sharpness 100. However, `pyzbar` still fails to decode it on the Raspberry Pi.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the black border from your image. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540322/6700019),
you can simply crop your image then feed the image to `pyzbar.decode()` function.

```
import cv2
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import numpy as np


def autocrop(image, threshold=0):
    """Crops any edges below or equal to threshold
    Crops blank image to 1x1.
    Returns cropped image.
    """
    if len(image.shape) == 3:
        flatImage = np.max(image, 2)
    else:
        flatImage = image
    assert len(flatImage.shape) == 2

    rows = np.where(np.max(flatImage, 0) > threshold)[0]
    if rows.size:
        cols = np.where(np.max(flatImage, 1) > threshold)[0]
        image = image[cols[0]: cols[-1] + 1, rows[0]: rows[-1] + 1]
    else:
        image = image[:1, :1]

    return image


if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = cv2.imread('sampleImage.png')
    crop = autocrop(image, 165)
    d = pyzbar.decode(crop)
    print(d)
```

Comment: I did that and it still behaves the same: decoding on RaspberryPi fails, and on Ubuntu decodes successfully.

Comment: Are you using this example for images read from the camera? I put the example for the provided image, not on any captured image from Pi camera.

Comment: The provided image was captured from Pi camera as well. It was just an example image which fully described the problem.