# Extracting retina region from 2D images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am working on Diabetic Retinopathy detection. The database comprises of 2D images that looks like this one:

[image: Original Image]

Now, I want to extract just the retina part from the images so that the final image looks like this one:

[image: New image]

I have tried `Canny` and `HoughCircles` but it failed. Is there any way to extract this region using `OpenCv` or `scikit-image` or `PIL`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop black edges with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538748/crop-black-edges-with-opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the foreground is so obvious, you can use simple thresholding to find it and then use [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) to get the crop you need:

```py
from skimage import io, color, filters, measure

image = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKBiU.jpg')
grayscale = color.rgb2gray(image)
foreground = (grayscale > filters.threshold_otsu(grayscale)).astype(int)
foreground_properties = measure.regionprops(foreground)[0]
cropped = image[foreground_properties.slice]
```

Comment: Thanks. Lemme try this