# OpenCV - minAreaRect // points is not a numerical tuple

Tags: python, opencv, contour

The error points is not a numerical tuple is being output.

```
# Converting image to a binary image
# ( black and white only image).
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

print(contours)

minArea = cv2.minAreaRect(contours)
```

The contours are:

```
(array([[[747, 305]],

       [[746, 306]],

       [[745, 306]],

       [[744, 307]],

       [[743, 308]],

       [[743, 309]],

       [[744, 310]],

       [[744, 311]],

       [[744, 312]],

       [[744, 313]],

       [[757, 306]],

       [[756, 306]],

       [[755, 306]],

       [[754, 306]],

       [[753, 306]],

       [[752, 305]],

       [[751, 305]],

       [[750, 305]],

       [[749, 305]],

       [[748, 305]]], dtype=int32),)
```

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - points is not a numerical tuple
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'points'

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which OpenCV version are you using? Depending on the version, findContours returns 2 or 3 parameters.

Comment: I'm using 4.5.5

Comment: `contours` is a list of lists. The lists being the points that make up a contour. In other words, you are passing a list of contours instead of individual contours to `minAreaRect`. You need to loop through all the contours, extract each individual contour and pass that to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the help I used the advice below and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv2.findContours` returns a list of contours. Each contour is a list of points. Therefore `contours` returned by it is not a list of points, but rather a list of lists of points.

`cv2.minAreaRect` on the other hand requires as input a single list of points, and therefore you get an error when you feed it with `contours`.

You can solve it by flattening the `contours` into a single list of points, like this:

```
contours_flat = np.vstack(contours).squeeze()
minArea = cv2.minAreaRect(contours_flat)
```

Altenatively you can get the `minAreaRect` for each contour in `contours` list by using (`idx` is the 0 based index of the contour):

```
minArea = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[idx])
```

You can see here more about contours: [Contours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html), [cv::findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga95f5b48d01abc7c2e0732db24689837b)

And about minAreaRect: [cv::minAreaRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/71447672/5294258