# Android not detecting Laser

Tags: opencv, android

I am new to **OpenCV**.

As I am trying to detect laser dot using this code. But there is no change in output.As I found that it's not detection laser. Kindly help me in fixing this issue. Here is my code

```
@Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat frameH;
        Mat frameV;
        Mat frameS;

        //static int a=1;
        List<Mat> mChannels= new ArrayList<>();

        Mat originalFrame=new Mat();
        Mat frame=new Mat();

        inputFrame.rgba().copyTo(originalFrame);
        inputFrame.rgba().copyTo(frame);

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(frame,frame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

        mChannels.clear();
        Core.split(frame, mChannels); // Split channels: 0-H, 1-S, 2-V
        frameH = mChannels.get(0);
        frameS = mChannels.get(1);
        frameV = mChannels.get(2);

        // Apply a threshold to each component
        Imgproc.threshold(frameH, frameH, 155, 160, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
        Imgproc.threshold(frameV, frameV, 250, 256, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

        // Perform an AND operation
        Core.bitwise_and(frameH, frameV, frame);

        frameH.release();
        frameV.release();
        frameS.release();

        frame.release();

        return originalFrame; // This function must return
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps a `List<Mat>` as the [documentation of `Core.split`](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#split(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.util.List)) seems to suggest? Although having written that code, you probably ought to know what you declared it as.

Comment: I copied this code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743809/opencv-android-track-laser-dot but confused.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately that's a fairly poor question, since it's missing [mcve] (and a good example why it's required). Anyway, a `List` of `Mat`s should do the trick.

Comment: can you please tell which class I should initialize orignalframe ?

Comment: Well, since I can't see the rest of the code, `originalFrame` appears to really just be a temporary variable, so you could just make it local to `onCameraFrame`. However, you may want to keep it persist in memory to reduce the number of allocations, in which case make it a member of the class that contains `onCameraFrame` and initialize it... I guess in the constructor?

Comment: my issue has been solved but now it's not detection laser. here is source code can you please tell me what should I do.

Comment: @DanMašek i have updated my code please check this.